# How to Change URL in current Browser session while selenium Test is running

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I need to change the URL while test is running . Example,

I'm on the https://www.google.com.au when i select first Link then i will be navigated to that particular link . So that is doing but then i need to update that link URL .

I tried below but it is not working .

```
        string myAccountUri = "my-account /#account-validation";
        string z = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestEnv"] + string.Join(",", myAccountUri));
        pageManager.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(z);
```

Comment: Navigate to the site you want your user to view first, then write the response of that page, then navigate to the URL *after* you've sent them to your page. Remember that web pages are stateless, though - so anything they do might stop the test. You need to handle that in what you send (like a static text page with no links explaining what's going on with a progress bar). If you get stuck on something specific, we're here for you.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger :- I'm already able to go to the page where i wanted to but my task is to re-enter the new url created in z variable .
with  pageManager.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(z); it is not doing anything . it should enter the url in browser .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code is working for me. it's just in myAccountUri white-space was creating issue while it was trying to navigateto the URL. Below fixed it already .

```
string myAccountUri = "my-account/#account-validation";
```